# function is being called but I dont know why

Tags: reactjs

can someone tell me why in the world the `drawCard()` function runs 4 times as it should and then 52 more times the deck is 52 items long it must be related
but this
`const initCard = ()=>{return deck.map((card,index)=>{return index<4 && drawCard(index%2===0?'player':'dealer')})}`

so I don't know why does it happen
here is the full component

```
import Box from '@mui/material/Box';
import { useEffect, useRef, useState } from 'react';
import Card from '../components/Card'
import {styles} from '../visuals/Styles'
import { drawCardAnimation  } from '../visuals/Animations'
 
function Gamepage() {

  const [deck, setDeck] = useState([]);
  /*let dealerHand=[];
  let playerHand=[];*/

  const [dealerHand, setDealerHand] = useState([]);
  const [playerHand, setPlayerHand] = useState([]);

  const [screenState, setScreenState] = useState('placeBet')

  const first = useRef(true) //in order to prevent the effect of react strict we use ref to keep alive the first var which tells us if the useEffect hasnt been executed yes

  useEffect(()=>
  {
    if(first.current){
      first.current =false;
      getDeck();
    }
  },[]);

  const getDeck = async () =>{
      const res = await fetch('http://localhost:5000/deck/shuffled');
      const data = await res.json();
      setDeck(data);
  }

  const initCard = ()=>{return deck.map((card,index)=>{return index<4 && drawCard(index%2===0?'player':'dealer')})}
  
  const countCards = (hand)=>{
    let res=0;
    return {"cardsCount":hand.map(({suit,number,imgPath})=>{ return number }).sort((a, b) => b-a).map((value)=>{
      if(value ===1 && res+11 <= 21)
        res +=11;
      else 
        res+=value;

      return res  
    })[hand.length-1], "isBusted": res<=21 ? false:true};
  }
  const isBlackJack = (hand)=>{
    return hand.length === 2 && countCards(hand).cardsCount === 21
  }
 const isPlayerWon= ()=>{
  isBlackJack(playerHand) && console.log("BLACK JACK !");
  return isBlackJack(playerHand) || (!countCards(playerHand).isBusted && countCards(dealerHand).isBusted) || (countCards(playerHand).cardsCount>=countCards(dealerHand).cardsCount && !countCards(playerHand).isBusted) 
 }

 const drawToDealer = ()=>{
  while(countCards(dealerHand).cardsCount<17){
      drawCard('dealer')}
    }

  const drawCard = (target) =>
  {
    console.log("drawn");
    let index = dealerHand.length + playerHand.length;

    if(deck[index]&& target==='dealer' && !dealerHand.includes(deck[index]))
      {
        //dealerHand.push(deck[index])
        setDealerHand((prev)=>[...prev, deck[index]])
      }

    else if(deck[index]&& target==='player'&& !playerHand.includes(deck[index]))
      { 
        //playerHand.push(deck[index]);
        setPlayerHand((prev)=>[...prev, deck[index]])
      }

    return deck[index]&& 
    <Card 
    key={index} 
    stl={index===1?styles.firstDealerCard:styles.card} 
    cardImg={( target==='dealer'&&dealerHand.length===1)?'upsidedownCard':deck[index].imgPath} 
    animation={drawCardAnimation(target==='dealer'?dealerHand.length-1:playerHand.length-1,target)}/>;
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <Box sx={styles.box}>
        {/*TODO find out why functions inside onClick does not work 
          and make the end game prompt on screen
        */}

        <Card stl={styles.deck} cardImg={'upsidedownCard'} />
        {
        (screenState==='placeBet')?
        <img src={require('../assets/btnPlaceBet.png')} alt='' style={styles.btnPlaceBet} onClick={()=>setScreenState('gameStart')} />
          :initCard()
        }

        {
          screenState==='gameStart' && <img src={require('../assets/btnHit.png')} alt='' style={styles.btnHit} onClick={()=>{ drawCard('player'); console.log(playerHand);}} />
        }

        {
          screenState==='gameStart' && <img src={require('../assets/btnStand.png')} alt='' style={styles.btnStand} onClick={()=>{ setScreenState('dilearsTurn')}} />
        }

        {
          screenState==='gameStart' && <img src={require('../assets/btnDouble.png')} alt='' style={styles.btnDouble} onClick={()=>{ console.log('money is doubled'); drawCard('player'); /*console.log(playerHand);*/;setScreenState('dilearsTurn')}} />
        }
        
        {
          screenState==='dilearsTurn' && <Card stl={styles.revealedCard} cardImg={dealerHand[0].imgPath} />
        }

        {
          screenState==='dilearsTurn' && drawToDealer()
        }

        {
          screenState==='dilearsTurn' && console.log(dealerHand.length)
        }

        {
          screenState==='dilearsTurn' &&console.log(isPlayerWon() ?
          `player wins ${countCards(playerHand).cardsCount} and dealer  ${countCards(dealerHand).cardsCount} ${countCards(dealerHand).isBusted ? 'dealer busted':''}`
          :
          `dealer wins ${countCards(dealerHand).cardsCount}  and player  ${countCards(playerHand).cardsCount} ${countCards(playerHand).isBusted ? 'player busted':''}`)
        }

        {screenState==='dilearsTurn' && setTimeout(()=>{
          console.log('game ended'); 
          setTimeout(()=>{
            setScreenState('placeBet')
          },2000);

          },3000)}
        
        
      </Box>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Gamepage
```

Comment: Please paste entire component

Comment: You are not changing the state, so the component will not render changes.

Comment: what state should I change ?

Comment: Seems like `playerHand` should be a state as you are trying to modify it

Comment: I have tried using both hand as a state but then when I wanted to push to them in the drawCard function I use ```setPlayerHand()``` and it gave an error too many renders

Comment: That's a different error caused by something else

Comment: Why does your `drawCard` function returns jsx?

Comment: because I want it to add a card at the screen too when the function is called

Comment: Where do you think that html tags would appear in the dom if you didn't specify the place? https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html#gatsby-focus-wrapper

Comment: well, I read this article and I didn't get what is wrong should I write ```root.render(<Card />);``` somewhere in my code is that is?
if not please explain in more detail what did you mean and maybe an explained solution